# hybridEnsemble package in R

Tags: r, ensemble-learning

I want to build a Bagged Logistic Regression Model in R. My dataset is really biased and has 0.007% of positive occurrences.

My thoughts to solve this was to use Bagged Logistic Regression. I came across the hybridEnsemble package in R. Does anyone have an example of how this package can be used? I searched online, but unfortunately did not find any examples.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would try to solve this is use the `h2o.stackedEnsemble()` function in the [h2o R package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=h2o).  You can automatically create more balanced classifiers by using the `balance_classes = TRUE` option in all of the base learners.  More information about how to use this function to create ensembles is located in the [Stacked Ensemble H2O docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html).

Also, using H2O will be way faster than anything that's written in native R.

Comment: Thanks Erin. I have never used h20. But I will try it.